# How to create a dataframe from a text file with the first word as a column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataset with millions of lines. I need a faster way to create the dataframe in the following format:-

```
   column_1   column_2
    1         line 1
    Yes       Go to School
    NO        Play video games for hours
```

file format:-

```
1 line 1
Yes Go to School
No Play video games for hours
```

Is there any faster way to perform this task using pandas like any inbuilt function or so?? there are approx. 3 million lines in the file.

Comment: What is your current approach and how long is it taking?

Comment: What is the logic here? You split by first space and everything on the right goes to second column?

Comment: @IoaTzimas That's right (at least from what I read). It's very straight forward to do using any libraries, but not sure how the OP is doing it and how long is it taking.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (it takes 20 seconds approx to load in my machine, i don't know if it's good enough for you though)

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    data = [line.split(' ', maxsplit=1) for line in f]

df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=['column_1', 'column_2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try regex to split file rows-

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='^(\S+)', names=['column_1', 'column_2'], engine='python', usecols=[1, 2])
```